# C# Module not executing in IIS Classic App Pool

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5, httpmodule, siteminder

I've got a custom developed module that I'm looking to integrate into an existing website. The website currently runs in Classic mode on IIS 7.5. We rely on Apache Jakarta and CA Siteminder ISAPI addins for authentication/etc so the module needs to execute after the ISAPI ones.

Right now, the module is not executing at all on my development server. It seems to work fine on IIS Express configured in classic mode.

Any thoughts on what the issues might be?

Comment: Could you show your webconfig?

Comment: For classic pipeline, you should stick to the old `<httpModule>` and `<httpHandler>`. And also for classic mode, managed things are running after IIS ISAPIs. So when you said "the module is not executing", you'd better check where you configured it. You can also use application level logging to see if the module is loaded at all.